# Running a command that includes an STDIN redirect with screen

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, heredoc, centos8, herestring

Using the [Gradle SSH plugin](https://gradle-ssh-plugin.github.io/) I deploy a `.jar` file to another machine.

I then would like to run that jar in a detached `screen` session.
This wouldn't be a problem if the application did not require input on STDIN, running `screen -dmS screen-name java -jar my.jar`.

I tried to provide the input (beside others approaches) in the following way using a *here-string*, yet I did not get any of them to work:

```
screen -dmS screen-name java -jar my.jar <<< "firstInputLine
SecondInputLine
"
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently solved this by first creating the detached `screen` session an then, with a second `screen` call, forwarding the input using screen's `stuff` command, not using a here-string anymore:

```
screen -dmS screen-name java -jar my.jar && 
screen -S screen-name -p 0 -X stuff "firstInputLine^MsecondInputLine^M"
```

(^M is interpreted as ENTER)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are piping the input to the screen command and not actually to the java process. I would do it the following way:

1. create a file with your input, something along the lines of `echo "foo" > input.txt`
2. `scp` that file to the machine
3. run the `screen` command and make the java process either read the file directly (if that program can do that) or pipe it properly by running a `bash` command instead of the `java` command directly. Something along the lines of `screen -dmS screen-name bash \"cat input.txt | java -jar ...\"`

Disclaimer: the above escaping is just approximate to get my point accorss ;-)

Comment: I would prefer a solution that does not require to manually create a file, but your hint with using `bash` might be helpful. I am just struggeling to escape everything right...